Export one row in datagridview C# into Excel template
I get this error:

GemBox.Spreadsheet.FreeLimitReachedException: 'Free version limitation has been exceeded (Free version is limited to 150 rows and 5 sheets). To control what happens when your application reaches free version limit use SpreadsheetInfo.FreeLimitReached event. For more information about evaluation

This is my code:
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Column1excel"].Index)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to convert the recorde into Excel File ?", "message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
           if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Column1excel"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
           {
               InsertIntoExcelTemplate("switchyard.XLSX");

               MessageBox.Show("Data inserted into Excel template successfully.");
           }
       }
   }

   if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Column1delet"].Index)
   {
       if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to delete the record?", "message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
       {
           if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Column1delet"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
           {
               // Retrieve the data associated with the clicked row
               con.Open();

               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from TB_report_trip where ID_trip=@ID_trip", con);

               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_trip", id);

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

               MessageBox.Show("are you sure want to delete it?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel.ToString());

               con.Close();
           }
       }
   }
}

private void InsertIntoExcelTemplate(string templateFilePath)
{
     SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

     ExcelFile workbook = ExcelFile.Load("switchyard.XLSX");

     GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

     int rowIndex = 1; // Start from the second row since the first row might contain headers

     foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
         int columnIndex = 0;

         foreach (DataGridViewCell dataGridViewCell in dataGridViewRow.Cells)
         {
             object cellValue = dataGridViewCell.Value;

             // GemBox.Spreadsheet uses 0-based indexes for columns
             worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value = cellValue;
             columnIndex++;
         }

         rowIndex++;
     }

     workbook.Save("Output.xlsx");
}

private void SpreadsheetInfo_FreeLimitReached(object sender, FreeLimitReachedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("GemBox.Spreadsheet free version limitation reached. Please purchase a license to remove this limitation.", "Limit Exceeded", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    // You may handle this event in other ways, such as limiting the number of rows or sheets used in your application.
}


An error message and a block of code is not a well thought out question we can answer. Tell us more about what it is you want to know/do

I have a table (datagridview) so i want to export one row from this table into excel template

Use a library like EPPlus to emit one of your datatable rows to an excel sheet

thanks for your information but i used this library it doesnot work

I'm one of the 100.7 million downloads of EPPlus; I promise it works

private void InsertIntoExcelTemplate(string templateFilePath)
will export all rows from this datagridview .Because using for-loop without index will get all rows.You need to set rowIndex in this function.
private void InsertIntoExcelTemplate(string templateFilePath,int rowIndex)
{
     SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

     ExcelFile workbook = ExcelFile.Load("switchyard.XLSX");

     GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

     if(rowIndex==0)
        rowIndex = 1; // Start from the second row since the first row might contain headers
     
     //ColumnIndex.You can use for-loop to get every value from this certain row in dataGridview1.

int colCount = dataGridView1.Items[0].Cells.Count;

for (int i=0 ; i<colCount ;i++)
{
     worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, i].Value = dataGridView1.Row[rowIndex].Cells[i].Value;
}


     workbook.Save("Output.xlsx");
}

